# Mover mouse para pixel da tela (XY)

Tags: c#, vb.net

Olá pessoal estou com um problema, bom eu já consegui pegar a posição do mouse em relação a form !

Para isso utilizei uma form com a borda NONE, maximizada, e opacidade 5% e quando o usuario clica nessa form ela fecha !

Para pegar a coordenada da form utilizei o evento MouseMove e fiz como abaixo. Para mandar para 2 textbox em outro form.

```
Posição.PosX.Text = e.X & vbLf
Posição.PosY.Text = e.Y & vbLf
```

Ele manda no seguinte estilo para cada TextBox, apenas o número: 0 / 0.

Porém eu notei que quando faço a função para mover o mouse até essa coordenada, ele move errado. Bom acontece que ele move tantos "x" / "y" a partir da posição do mouse. E isso não era para acontecer, era para mover até o pixel da TELA.

Se estiver confuso é o seguinte: ele move 200 e 300 do cursor, não move para o pixel 200 e 300 da tela.

Para mover utilizei o seguinte:

```
Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - PosX.Text, Cursor.Position.Y - PosY.Text)
```

Então resumindo:

O mouse é movido utilizando sua localização, o que eu quero é que ele mova utilizando os pixels da TELA.

Também gostaria de saber se é possivel que ele sempre mova o cursor para o local especificado mesmo com a aplicação em segundo Plano.

Eu já vi alguns programas assim, e criados em VB.NET porém não possuo acesso ao código fonte. PODE SER EM VB NET OU C#.

Se estiver meio confuso fala abaixo que tento explicar melhor ainda..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

está meio confuso a questão, mas aparentemente, você quer definir a posição do mouse com base em algum controle ?! , sendo assim utilize o PointToScreen

```
Cursor.Position = textBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

Comment: Opa eu já consegui o que queria tipo o ponteiro do mouse era movido XY dele mesmo não era movido para XY da tela. Mas eu removi o Cursor.Position e funcionou ;)